# Push local changes to my live hosting

Tags: git, github

I want to know what is the recommended workflow with `git`.

I have a local environment on `xampp`, I make some changes, update my local git, push the updated files to my `github repo` and then upload the files via ftp.
I want that when I push the files to my `github repo`, my live website (bluehost server) will get the updated files too, without using ftp.
Here my current workflow:

1. changes on my localhost
2. commit to my local repo (git bash)
3. push to github repo
4. upload the files via ftp to my bluehost server

How can I improve my workflow?

I  heard **SSH** but I have no idea what it means and how to use it, SSH is the best way?

Thanks.

Comment: You can simply ssh into your prod server and run a git pull or use an automated workflow service such as CodeShip to automate this for you

Answer (score 1):

You can clone your repository directly to bluehost server and add GitHub-webhook that performs a git pull on your bluehost folder every time you perform a push to github

Answer (score 0):

For this i use sourcetre and bitbucket. Bitbucket have pipeline (deployment tool) feature.

Comment: Ok, and if I want to use with github?

Comment: in github private repo is premium feature

Answer (score 0):

A manual solution is to create a git repo in the folder for the live website. Then add the URL for this repo as a remote to your local repo. Finally, whenever you are ready to release an update, just push from your local development repo to the live website repo.

Comment: @ronjacob You can do this with either ssh or https.

Comment: So why peoples use ssh and not https? Do you a tutorial about using https?

Comment: @ronjacob First of all, you can use HTTPS, not HTTP. HTTPS requires that you enter a user name and password for each transaction, such as a push or a pull. Alternatively, you can save your password in a password wallet. SSH is more popular because you configure a public key for authentication and then forget about it.

Comment: Great. Maybe you have tutorial  for beginners?

Comment: @ronjacob Try googling for one.